# Phonegap on android support localstorage?

Tags: android, html, cordova, android-webview

My question here is twofold:

1) Does Droidgap (or Phonegap for Android) support localstorage in the browser. Does phonegap simply make use of android's native browser (and if so, does this mean it supports html 5 local storage?)

2) Is there a way to debug an html5 webapp running on the phonegap platform in Eclipse? I'm running my application and it fails everytime I send a request to my server, however I see no error in logcat...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using facebook plugin for phonegap?

Comment: OK. Of course it support html5 localstorage. Browse via ddms and find the file (something like 0000000000000001.db) Look for it. If the file is there you can open it via some software which can open sqlite files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap does indeed support localstorage.

I was able to receive logs from my app by inserting log statements in the HTML/Javascript itself and look at the config files server-side. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes Phonegap supports localstorage, as you can check here
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage

Your javascript output should all appear in logcat.

Comment: It doesn't, any idea why? And thanks for the link. USB Debuggins is enabled and I even hardcoded debugging=true

Comment: can't accept your answer until you respond to this comment ^, thanks